# While making a dataframe in R why are some columns returned as NA despite the data being present

Tags: r

I'm trying to import 100k+ data from a`tsv` file into `data frame`. I used `read.csv.raw` from `iotools` package in `R` for faster execution as the normal ones are taking too much time. It worked like a charm and I was able to read the data within a sec. Later, I observed that some column had data in the database but while importing it is showing as `NA`.

Can anyone help explain why this is happening?

There are 32 columns with 100k+ rows
(just naming it with an alias because I could not copy the whole data as it's huge).

```
Student Roll NO Student Name    Student Total  Marks    Students Marks English  Students Marks Maths    Students Marks Science  FinalYearProjectMarks   FinalYearProjectName
1   ABC 20  24  23  12  98  Smart City
2   DEF 20  21  22  15  56  City as a Wifi Hub
3   GHI 18  8   21  23  73  Oil And Gas
4   XYZ 15  10  10  23  72  Mobile Pro and cons
5   SEW 20  25  11  25  85  Smart City 2
```

```
library(iotools)
 refdata <- read.csv.raw("D:\\Final Report\\Students_all.tsv", header=TRUE, sep="\t",quote = "")
 names(refdata)
```

```
[1] "Student_Roll_No"                "Students_Name"                  "Student_Total_Marks"           
 [4] "Students_Marks_English"         "Students_Marks_Maths"           "Students_Marks_Science"        
 [7] "Students_Marks_History"         "Students_Marks_Geography"       "Students_Marks_Social_Work"    
[10] "FinalYearProjectName"        "FinalYearProjectMarks"       "Students_Address"              
[13] "Students_Admission_Date"        "Students_Enrollment_No"         "Student_Ethinic"               
[16] "Students_Parents_Enrollment_No" "Contact_No"                     "Review_Performace_Grade"       
[19] "X"                              "Last_Years_Grade"               "Current_Years_Grade"           
[22] "Last_Years_Marks"               "Percentage"                     "Grade_Review"                  
[25] "Performace_Remark"              "Date_of_Issue"
```

Now after the import of the table we can see the `refdata$FinalYearProjectName`,

```
Actual
FinalYearProjectName:-
NA,
NA,
NA,
NA,
NA,
```

It is clearly showing `NA` instead of the actual data.

Expected

```
FinalYearProjectName:-
Smart City,
City as a Wifi Hub,
Oil And Gas,
Mobile Pro and cons,
Smart City 2,
```

Comment: can you update the question with output of `names(refdata)`? Did you also look at `data.table::fread`?

Comment: @Sonny Yes, tried data.table::freed

Comment: I think sharing some data will help. May be you can show few sample rows from the tsv files